# Login ldap java

Tags: java, ldap

I have the bellow code and works

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=" + user + ",cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://93.5.95.5:389");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);

LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
NamingEnumeration objs = ctx.search("dc=test,dc=com",   "(objectClass=*)", searchControls);
```

But I would like to do login for uid. I changed

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=" + user + ",cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com");
```

I'm getting error:

```
Details: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only Bind using a Distinguished name which appears to be:

```
"cn=" + user + ",cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com"
```

You could login as a different user (Service account) and then search for "uid=user" which would return the Distinguished Name.

We have some [example code that does something similar](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/master/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/BasicJndiSearchsvc.java).